Code runs in IDE normally but opens terminal and closes it immediately when double clicking the file
The code is:
import random
import time
import pyautogui as pag

print("The program has initiated!")
print("To stop the program, just close it")

while True:
    x = random.randint(600,800)
    y = random.randint(200,600)
    pag.moveTo(x,y,0.5)
    time.sleep(3)

When I run this in PyCharm it works normally, but when I run the source file by double clicking it, it just opens terminal and immediately closes.
i also have a few other projects that also dont work when i double click them. they use pygame and tkinter and the app window isnt opening
I tried changing the file type to .txt file and back to .py file, still just opens terminal and immediately close
afterwards i tried opening a cmd in the file's folder and run it through that which worked but i want it so i can just run the file and have it work

no way to say whats the actual cause but pycharm has probably installed the dependencies into their own respective virtual env's and when you try to run the scripts, those env's are not activated and thus, script fails.

You don't say what terminal program you are using (or what operating system, for that matter), but many terminals can be configured to stay open if the shell they are running inside, exits. Maybe you can force it to stay open, and you have a chance to see the error message.  Also, "double clicking" a program is not  a way I would use for debugging. Just start a shell inside the terminal and then call your program from this command line.

One more problem: You are importing modules which need to be installed, but I can not see how you set up the environment, so that Python can find those installed modules. You also have provided any information on how you configured the effect on "double clicking", and I don't know which Python then invoked, nor whether there is any Python going to be invoked!

There are multiple possible problems. It sometimes happens that your program is successful but the terminal just close immediately. for example see here. However in your case I think it is more likely that pycharm uses a different version of python than your terminal (i.e. by double clicking) and that the pycharm version has random/time/pyautogui installed but the version in your terminal does not.

how do i fix it then?

assuming you are using windows you could open your script in an allready existing terminal. I.E. first open powershell (for example) in your folder, by using shift + right click and click open powershell window here and then type : python .py
Alternatively you could add raw_input() at the end of your script and then the programs waits for some user input.
